# Finding the origin of Postgres/Sequelize duplicate alias error (code 42712)

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) to manage by Postgres SQL database in a node.js project. I'm running into namespace errors but can't for the life of me figure out why.

The code that works:

```
// db variable holds initialized database connection
const link = name => ( {
    through: db.define( name, {
        amount: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        unit: Sequelize.STRING,
        dataSource: Sequelize.STRING
    } ),
    as: name + 's'
} )

// All model variables (Material, Component etc) have model names
// identical to their variable names (bit without capitals)

Material.belongsToMany( Material, link( 'materialchildmaterial' ) )

Component.belongsToMany( Component, link( 'componentchildcomponent' ) )

Input.belongsToMany( Input, link( 'inputchildinput' ) )

Component.belongsToMany( Component, link( 'componentchilddependency' ) )
```

The moment I add the following things break:

```
Input.belongsToMany( Component, link( 'componentchildinput' ) )
```

The error:

```
{ name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent:
   { name: 'error',
     length: 177,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42712',
     file: 'parse_relation.c',
     line: '420',
     routine: 'checkNameSpaceConflicts'  },
  original:
   { name: 'error',
     length: 177,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42712',
     file: 'parse_relation.c',
     line: '420',
     routine: 'checkNameSpaceConflicts'  } }
```

From the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/errcodes-appendix.html) code 42712 stands for 'DUPLICATE ALIAS'.

My confusion: I am using unique names for everything (afaik). When I change the Input <--> Component link's name to 'randomthing' the error does not appear.

I've been stuck at this for a good day now. Any clues appreciated.

Comment: Turn on query log in PG to see what the erroneous query is. Also your question is missing the definition of the models.

Comment: The queries are rather huge, any tips on what we're looking for? The models are not very interesting, just some strings, I figured only the names were relevant, which is why I added that the names are identical to the variable names.

Comment: Well, I guess you're gonna have something like `JOIN component AS component` twice and then you'll have to figure out how to pass an alias to `belongsToMany`: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-elements-of-a-belongsto-association-with-an-alias

Comment: And sorry if I sound a bit like I don't want to give you the answer, I just don't know node.js,

Comment: No worries. I'm grateful for the help. I'm already passing an alias using the `as:` option. This is the crux of what confuses me, I am setting unique aliases, and yet I'm getting duplicate alias errors...

Comment: Well, I can't see you passing unique aliases anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: The `name` parameter is used to create unique alias names. The `as: name + 's'` should create alias names that are unique since I'm not passing the same link name twice.

Comment: Well, in that case check the query log to see how it's translated to SQL.

Comment: @Mentor did you ever solve this issue? Facing the same problem